# Sinking of the SS Galway castle in 1918, is there a complete list of missing passengers

Tags: 1910s, manifest, devon, south-africa

Is there any way to find a list of those whose lives were lost in the sinking of the SS Galway Castle in 1918?

Newspapers at the time give details if they were local to the area and also the number, rated by passenger class, but I can't find a list of names.  I believe my great aunt, Ruth Hendry, who had recently married a discharged SA soldier was on the ship, but she was drowned although I believe he survived.

Comment: Sorry her name was Ruth Whyte, or White.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH:SE.  You should edit that into your question, rather than posting it as a comment.

Comment: The passenger list can be found on Ancestry, does this answer your question? See [Locating passenger list for fatal voyage of SS Galway Castle?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/12250/locating-passenger-list-for-fatal-voyage-of-ss-galway-castle)